# Formula for binary to decimal

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program to change binary input into decimal and I saw this code on another website, but I don't understand how the formula in this code works to change binary into decimal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    long int binaryNumber, decimalNumber = 0, j = 1, remainder;

    printf("Enter any binary number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &binaryNumber);

    while (binaryNumber != 0) {
         remainder = binaryNumber % 10;
        decimalNumber = decimalNumber + remainder * j;
        j = j * 2;
        binaryNumber = binaryNumber / 10;
    }

    printf("Equivalent decimal value: %ld", decimalNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Why not build it and trace through execution with your debugger?

Comment: @MartinJames: that was my first thought, but I thought I would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

This code uses the modulus operation to pick a 1 or a 0 off the right side of the binary number that was entered and store it in `remainder`. Each 1 or 0, stored in `remainder`, is then multiplied by the value it represents, represented by `j`, and then added to the `decimalNumber`. The binary number is then divided by 10 to shift all the digits to the right. This repeats until there are no more 1's left in the binary number.